# Parler lentement vs parler doucement?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Whenever I have trouble understanding a native speaker, I ask them to speak more slowly by requesting something to the effect of "Parlez plus lentement, s'il vous plaît."

But I have more than once had someone infer what I was going to say and complete the sentence for me, except they say *doucement* instead of *lentement*.

Is *lentement* the wrong word for this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both « lentement » and « doucement » can be used with the meaning of « moins vite ».

> Pouvez-vous parler plus **doucement**, s'il vous plaît ?

In the sentence above, « parler doucement » can mean either « parler lentement {speak slowly} » or « parler à voix basse {speak quietly} », depending on context.

Although... in order to eliminate any ambiguity, it is more common to use « lentement »:

> Pouvez-vous parler plus **lentement**, s'il vous plaît ?

Comment: Actually, I consider using "doucement" with the meaning of "lentement" as a mistake, even if it's a common one

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys Hi. Someone in a fit of excitement/temper tends to speak **fast and loud.** In such a specific case, the use of "doucement" might come in handy: "Can you calm down a little bit, speak **more slowly and quietly**?" Qu'en penses-tu ? :)

Comment: J'en pense du bien. "parle plus doucement, les enfants dorment" (speak more quietly, the children are sleeping), but "répète plus lentement, je n'ai pas pu noter" (repeat slowlyer, I couldn't write it down)